# What is the best practice to get related/nested data from REST API?

Tags: rest, api, http, django-rest-framework, client-server

For example: We have a User model, which in turn has several Company entities. I see 2 solutions:

1) Classical. Make an API like:

```
/users/ 
/users/3/ 
/users/3/companies/
```

and issue `/users` or `companies` request separately. However, if we need to have both `user` and his/her `companies` information in one view (on Angular2) - we need to send 2 requests to the server.

2) Put the related/nested data inside the level-1 object model. In request:

```
/users/3/
```

the server will provide information about the User, together with his Companies. In this case we get all information for 1 request. But again, the company has an unlimited number of Storage entities. What if they are required in one separate view?

I'm more inclined to the first option, but I'm confused by the description of the REST style: "The view must fully represent the resource." Satisfaction of this requirement can lead to a partition of the resource into child resources and, accordingly, to smaller representations. "

Please, help with advice, I doubt in connection with the lack of experience what decision will be correct in this case. Oh yes, I forgot, Backend on Django (Python) using Django-Rest-Framework - All this is a SaaS for ~ 1000 users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Approach 1` is an an ideal approach for REST. But when it comes to designing APIs for the displaying information on the UI it involves much more than just partitioning the APIs as per resources.

So I would suggest including the `Company` information in the `User` API. But as you suggested `Company` object can have very large list of `Storage` objects, in this case I would recommend including only the necessary and sufficient fields of `Company` model into `User` API. So that you will be able to render one view. And then later when user expands the `Company` section then you can pull the left-over fields from `/company/<id>` API.

This way you will have lesser API calls for the hits where user doesn't look for `Company` details and your API will be light weight as well.